# Where would I ask a question regarding the cycle time of a SIMATIC PLC with high-speed analog module

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a quite specific question regarding the sampling rate of a hs-anolog modul in combination with the cycle-time of my program (TIA-portal V15) running on a Siemens Simatic CPU 1510SP-1 PN for ET 200SP.

On which site of the SE-universe, if at all, could I ask such a question?
Does anyone have experience with asking questions about SIMATIC PLC's?

Comment: You can use the [siemens][plc] tags on StackOverflow, but the odds for a trustworthy answer in a reasonable time for such a module-specific question are quite low.  Siemens provides good technical support for their customers, like [this](https://w3.usa.siemens.com/automation/us/en/industrial-controls/product-support/Pages/service-support.aspx) or [this](https://new.siemens.com/at/de/unternehmen/ueber-uns/kontakt-geschaeftskunden.html).

Comment: This very likely belongs on [electronics.se].

Comment: @forest & Uphill I tried searching for `[siemens], [plc]` as suggested and the results on either SO (24 questions, some of them quite basic) or EE (4 questions) weren't really promising as already implied by Uphill. Basically EE would be a better fit since the question is  more hardware related than about programming in AWL or FUP. I found the [siemens support forum](https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf/WW/de) but imo it would be nice if such a topic would receive more coverage/be more popular in the SE-universe ;)

Comment: @UphillLuge If you or forest want to compile the gathered infos in the comments I'd be gladly accepting the summary as an answer (answering my own questions seems a bit.., well odd in such a case)